# How correct add file in useState with React/TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, file-upload

I am trying to add a file to my state . This state consists of an object where there is a line and there is a file itself. I ran into errors from TypeScript, which I can’t fix in any way.

This is the interface for the state

```
interface newDefaultSoundInterface {
    name: string,
    file: File| null,
}
```

This is a state

```
const [newDefaultSound, setNewDefaultStore] = useState<newDefaultSoundInterface>({name : '', file : null});
```

And this is the code of both inputs

```
<input type="text" className="popup__input" placeholder="Enter name Game"
                           value={newDefaultSound.name}
                           onChange=
                               {
                                   (event) => {
                                       setNewDefaultStore({...newDefaultSound, name: event.target.value}
                                       )
                                   }
                               }/>

                    <input type="file"

                           onChange={
                               (event) => {
                                   setNewDefaultStore({...newDefaultSound, file : event.target.files[0]}
                                   )
                                   console.log(newDefaultSound.file);
                               }}

                    />
```

Error that are in input from TypeScript

TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

Comment: The `file` property in your interface is `FileList`, but you're trying to assign a value of `File` to it. If you want to operate only on a single file, perhaps you need to change it to `File | null` or make it optional `File`.

Comment: @tromgy thanks! I fixes this problem, but TS2531: Object is possibly 'null' remained

Comment: For the latter, you can refer to this [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html#strict-null--undefined-checks).